# Does timestamps need the nullable false declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does timestamps need the nullable false declaration, while creating an ActiveRecord object.

```
t.timestamps null: false
```

Comment: No, they don't. What made you think so?

Comment: Most of the documentation in rails site seems to contain this information and I have never seen that before. Hence the question?

Comment: Also, here in 2018, my Rails 4.2 generator inserted that `null: false` for me. I'd never seen it before (been a few years since I worked with Rails).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to declare `null: false` for timestamps. Rails handle it itself, you should not play with these attrs from your code.

If still you want it not to be null, even forcefully, you will need to mention it as `null: false` i.e.:

```
t.timestamps null: false
```

Comment: `null: false` makes sense only if you know that there can be records inserted without involving ActiveRecord::Base subclasses and you don't want to have records with empty created/updated at fields.

Answer (score 4):

`t.timestamps null: false` is short-hand form of

```
  t.column :created_at,  :datetime
  t.column :updated_at,  :datetime
```

And both are same.
For more details , [Short-hand examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html)